# Split table in two with saving relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `addresses` with `country_iso2_code` and `country_id` fields, and table `countries` with `iso2_code` field. Now `country_id` and `iso2_code` fields are empty. I want to transfer `country_iso2_code` from `addresses` table to `iso2_code` in `country` table and set relationships between tables with `country_id` field. Please, help to find a solution.

Example:
table `addresses`
id | country_iso2_code | country_id
1  | US                | null
2  | US                | null
3  | FR                | null

Result:
table `addresses`
id | country_iso2_code | country_id
1  | US                | 1
2  | US                | 2
3  | FR                | 3
table `countries`
id | iso2_code
1  | US
2  | US
3  | FR

Comment: Sure, show us sample data and the expected output, and maybe you'll get an answer.

Comment: Here's the sample.

Comment: Why does `US` have two different `country_id` values (1 and 2) ?

Comment: It's OK. I need this. Please, don't ask why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `countries` if it doesn't already exist, populate it using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, then update `addresses`:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (id int, iso2_code varchar(10));

INSERT INTO countries (id, iso2_code)
SELECT id, country_iso2_code
FROM addresses

UPDATE addresses
SET country_id = id
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted. But first I was needed to execute `INSERT` command and then `update` `country_id` because I have FK on this field.